# Instance Objects on a Line Mesh or Spline

Tags: mesh, splines, geometry-nodes

I want to create an antennae for a wasp that I could move around easily for animation. I want to use cone objects that are instanced on a line and are oriented to the next point. I thought about using geometry nodes, but I don't know how to get the objects to rotate toward the next point on the line. Is there something I'm missing or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why are you not using bones?

Comment: @moonboots Ah, I forgot about them! Geez, that probably would work better wouldn't it. I'll leave this question open still, since there is probably a use for object instancing on a line with drivers and the such.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this with Geometry Nodes, you have several options depending on how flexible you want to keep it and what exactly you want to do.

A general simple approach would be to compute the direction vectors of the points along a curve and use them as rotation for your objects instantiated at the points.

[image]

Another approach would be this one: [How to orient a point to the next one with geometry node? (Curve follow)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228629/)