# How to orient a point to the next one with geometry node? (Curve follow)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working on a vines field and I want to use geometry node to instanced a collection of vine trees following a curve. I'm using Blender 2.93 so I converted my bezier spline to a mesh and used it with a Point Instance and now I need to orient each vine to the next one as a "curve follow" does.
How can I do that? Please help!
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? In the screenshot, you already have instanced vines on the edge. Can you please elaborate on what you want to do

Comment: I juste want to orient the instanced objects following the green arrows in the screenshot by calculating the z angle from the current point to the next one. Sorry I hope I am clear.

Comment: Can You share the blend file? It will make things a lot easier. Just upload it to https://pasteall.org/blend/ and share the link.

Comment: I don't think that sharing the blend file could help because there is nothing more than it seen in the screenshot.
The vines are pruned according to a very specific mode and there remains only one branch that must be attached to a thread that connects each tree. So these branches must point in a direction following the wire (here the curve)

Comment: Don't think it is possible in 2.93 unfortunately

Comment: @Gorgious I tried with Blender 3 alpha and I don't think it is possible nether...
Why we can't just make loop trough points? -_-

Comment: It's definitely possible in 3.0 but even more confusing than the standard array + curve which is already not straightforward. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGyZ_o3TkCE

Comment: Oh man! I was so happy to read this! But unfortunatly it does not solve my problem...
He never show its geometry node setup in his video + in my case I need to scattered multiple objects. I have a collection of 4 different vine trees for that. That is why I tried to achieve this using geometry node and not just array+curve instancing. I thing I will forget procedural methode and I will do it by script.
Oh by the way in the video it is not Blender 3 but 2.93

Comment: it works if your curve is just 2D....on 3.0.0 ...i tested that. But if you started moving points of the curve in z-directiions it doesn't work anymore unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily solved with Blender 3+.

Either you do it like here in the screenshot:

[image]

...or you calculate the direction vector for your rotation by yourself using the points:  [Instance Objects on a Line Mesh or Spline](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216395/)