# how could I align each stitch to follow the path of the curve and point in the direction of normals?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a stitch generator but I have the problem: how could I align each stitch to follow the path of the curve and point in the direction of normals? adding a normal and euler to vector doesn't work

[image: geometry nodes]

Comment: Hello ! Try the normal output of the Curve to Points node

Comment: you say normal curve to points to rotation instance on points?

Comment: nope, to the Align Euler to Vector input

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259156/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228629

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216395